# JOLT transformation for references

Tags: json, reference, mapping, jolt

I'm looking for a JOLT transformation for replacing a reference by it's entity:

My input is as follows:

```json
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstname": "Max"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "firstname": "Mel"
    }
  ],
  "special-role": {
    "id": 4
  }
}
```

My expected output should be:

```json
{
  "special-role" : {
     "firstname": "Mel"
  }
}
```

There is already an example on SO [A JOLT transformation question about mapping reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74686662/a-jolt-transformation-question-about-mapping-reference) but I couldn't figure out the solution for my problem anyway. I haven't yet find out how to substitute the fixed value **`"4"`** in **`"@(2,users.4.firstname)": "&"`** by the value under

```json
"special-role": {
    "id": 4
}
```

My latest try of the spec was:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "users": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.@(1,id).&"
        }
      },
      "special-role": "&"
    }
  },   
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "special-role": {
        "id": {
          "@(2,users.4.firstname)": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The outermost layer ( **&2** ) on the RHS for the first
  transformation is redundant
- The integer keys of the objects( **&2** ) on the RHS might be matched
  with the value of `special-role` ( **@(2,&)** ) on the LHS within the
  second transformation

So, you can use :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "users": {
        "*": {
          "fir*": "@(1,id).&" // pick the attribute "firstname" only
        }
      },
      "*": { // case of "special-role"
        "*": "&1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,&)": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]